# TP-LINK Archer D7: no ports forwarding/virtual servers in "Wireless Router Mode" (Ethernet as WAN)

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I recently switched my network provider from ADSL to Wi-Max. I'm using the same router, a *TP-LINK Archer D7* ([manual here](http://www.tp-link.it/resources/document/Archer_D7_V1_User_Guide_1910010943.pdf)): with the ADSL provider I was using the integrated modem, but now I use a "special" Ethernet port on the router for WAN (TP-LINK calls this ""Wireless Router Mode").

The Internet connection works as expected, but now **no port forwarding works anymore**, while it was OK with the ADSL provider.

The PC with the services is connected via Ethernet cable to the router.

Said PC has a statically-assigned LAN IP address. This IP is set as DMZ, but I also created port forwarding rules for it.

The firewall on the router is disabled.

The firewall on the PC is disabled.

Both the WAN port and the PC Ethernet port are in the same VLAN (actually, the VLAN function is disabled when the router is configured to use the Ethernet port as WAN).

I'm fresh out of ideas: the only other factors that come to my mind are:

- the Wi-Max provider is blocking incoming traffic - but I verified this before the switch, and they said "no blocking"
- This router doesn't allow ports forwarding in WAN mode - this sound unlikely, since the web interface is very polished and the "virtual servers" section is available in WAN mode too + I found no reference to this limit into the manual

I've contacted both the ISP and TP-LINK, but neither replied yet.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my Wi-Max provider replied: they where blocking my ports. The lifted the block and now everything works as expected.

Lesson learned: never trusts sales representative, always trust tech :-(